# If clause optimization

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style

I need to write an IF clause (we're using Java 8). The relevant variables are `group`, `privilege`, `role`, `level` and `class`. There is an `action` that needs to be performed in certain case. I've written the alghoritm in the following way:

```
if (group == G1) {
  if (privilege == P1) {
    // Perform the action if a user has this particular privilege
    perform_action_and_exit();
  } else {
    if (role == R1) {
      if ((level <= 2 && class == C1) || (level == 1 && (class == C2 || class == C3))) {
        perform_action_and_exit();
      }
      // Ignore other combinations of level and class
    }
    // Ignore other roles
  }
} else {
  // Perform the action for any group other than G1
  perform_action_and_exit();
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this condition?

Thanks.

Comment: You can put the conditions each in 1 function/method... think about single responsibility and code complexity

Comment: In all these cases it seems that the only thing you want to do is `perform_action_and_exit()` - so if you'll organize the conditions in methods as B001 suggested, you'll be able to do something like: `if (shouldExit()) { perform_action_and_exit(); }`

Comment: It depends on what is a cleaner way in your eyes. The way it's built right now you can only abstract things, I think, so you might encode this validation in a specialized objects, which chain together and can return either a next stage, shortcut stage or a no-op. For example, `GroupHandler.get(group)` which returns `StagedGroupHandler` if it's a `G1` or otherwise a `ShortcutHandler` (the one which will just return action executing stages and won't do any validations). That will, however, simply split the clause and hide it away, not eliminate or generally improve it.

Comment: What are the allowed values for `level`?

Comment: `class` can't be a variable, by the way.

Comment: Be sure to add a unit test for the existing code, then try some of the suggestions.  And consider how easy/hard it would be to add a new condition.

Comment: Just a suggestion for changing the title: This question isn't about optimization but making the code cleaner. The JVM will optimize it for you. So just go ahead, clean up the code (I'll put my vote on one of the answers), make new one-liner methods if it makes it cleaner. They won't make it slower.

Comment: Beyond that, many people put in quite some effort to help you with your problem. It feels just strange to notice that you obviously none of that input even worth an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, you need to separate the action from the test:

```
if (shouldPerform()) {
    perform_action_and_exit();
}
```

Sometimes, early exits make the code clear:

```
boolean shouldPerform() {
    if (group != G1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (role != R1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (level > 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (class == C1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (level != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return class == C2 || class == C3;
}
```

Sometimes, they don't. Just look at this and decide if you can understand it at first glance. You may have been told something like

- The only privileged group is G1, others are unrestricted.
- Only R1 can do a privileged action...
- ...

and then this early exits map exactly to the description.

In no case I'd recommend a complicated boolean expression. Anything spanning more than a line or two is too hard to understand. Using methods or variables with simple expressions can lead to much more readable code.

---

*Don't be bothered with efficiency here.* It's quite possible that all your versions of the condition will lead to equally fast code as the JVM inlines methods and transforms expression aggressively. *So don't needlessly micro-optimize, that's what the machine is for.*

Moreover, I'd bet that the execution of `perform_action_and_exit` takes at least four orders of magnitude longer than the test. The test may take some tens of *nanoseconds* (pessimistically assuming branch mispredictions), while the action probably accesses a database which means some *milliseconds*.

Answer (score 2):

You can reorganize and simplify your conditions using [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)):

```
if (group != G1
    || privilege == P1
    || role == R1
            && (level <= 2 && class == C1
                || level == 1 && (class == C2 || class == C3))
) {
    perform_action_and_exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, think if you really need to violate [Tell don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html).

Your code gains some status information, to then make decisions based on that. In a good OO model, you simply tell some object: "do the right thing". And then you rely on polymorphism to make sure that `doTheRightThing()` is the right thing for the current status.

If you don't want to go down that path, you should at least look into the *[single layer of abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction)* principle. Meaning: turn your condition expressions into small helper methods, so that your code reads:

```
if (isXCondition()) { 
  doX();
}
if (isYCondition()) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is sample refactoring to make your code cleaner, it can further be refactor if perform_action_and_exit() is the same method all throughout your code

```
if (group == G1) {
  doG1Stuff();
} else {
  // Perform the action for any group other than G1
  perform_action_and_exit();
}

void doG1Stuff(){
 if (privilege == P1) {
    // Perform the action if a user has this particular privilege
    perform_action_and_exit();
  } else {
    if (shouldActionBePerformed()) {
        perform_action_and_exit();
    }
  }
}

boolean shouldActionBePerformed(){
    return role == R1 && (level <= 2 && class == C1) || (level == 1 && (class == C2 || class == C3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A **declarative** solution in case of multiple conditions in business logic is definitely more verifiable and traceable. A nested if-complex is not. Declarative you have the final criteria with which you called the action.

However if you do not want to use expression language, the java scripting API, JShell, then one must do something like:

```
class Criteria {
    Group group;
    Privilege privilege;
    Role role;
    Level level;
}
class GuardedAction {
    String caseName; // For tracability, an auditing name.
    Predicate<Criteria> guard;
    Runnable action;
}

List<GuardedAction> guardedActions;
```

Fill this list, maybe from XML. And *version numbers* are useful in order to retrace "bugs" that a customer reports in an old log.

```
Criteria criteria = ...
for (GuardedAction ga : guardedActions) {
    if (ga.guard.test(criteria)) {
        System.out.println(ga.caseName);
        Logger.log(Level.INFO(ga.toString()); // With a detailed toString.
        ga.action.run();
        break;
    }
}
```

A nested if with business logic is hard to discuss on.

Answer (score 1):

the code seems messy, you've repeated the `perform_action_and_exit();` three times. think of single responsibility.

```
//all the code should be replaced by this:
if(should_perform_action_and_exit()){
   perform_action_and_exit();
}
....
```

then create methods/class (whatever fits the purpose better) for each action

```
boolean should_perform_action_and_exit(){

   return groupCheck() || privilageCheck() || roleCheck();

}
```

now the last three methods:

```
boolean groupCheck(){
   return group != G1;
}

boolean privilageCheck(){
   return privilege == P1;
}

boolean roleCheck(){
   return (role == R1)  &&  ((level <= 2 && class == C1) || (level == 1 && (class == C2 || class == C3)));
}
```

the above might look like more code, but the readability is improved for later.